# Defragmenting partitions with Raid 0

Tags: ubuntu, defragment, raid-0

In my current disk configuration it is 2+2 TB Raid 0. Since this 4TB of space was almost full, I installed two more disks in Raid 0. (2+2 TB) I have 8 TB of volume space in total.

But in Ubuntu, the first 4 TB and the 4 TB I added later are in separate partitions. Do I have to combine them? Will `sda4` start to fill up when the first disk (`sda3`) is full?

If I have to merge, how can I do it? Without data loss on the first disk (`sda3`). There is very little space left in the first part.

[image: GParted partitions]

[image: GParted disk info]

Answer (score 0):

> Will Sda4 start to fill up when the first disk (sda3) is full

No, they're completely separate filesystems. It's like having C:\ and D:\ in Windows.

They're on the same *disk,* however (both partitions are on 'sda' which has been correctly expanded to 8 TB by the RAID controller), so you shouldn't have created the sda4 partition at all – you should have *resized sda3* to fill the newly added space. (You can do this from within GParted; Ext4 can be expanded even while mounted.)

1. Unmount and delete the 'sda4' partition.
2. Use GParted's "Move/Resize" option to expand the 'sda3' partition to the full size of the 'sda' device.

Comment: How can I do it from within Gparted. If I delete sda4, will I have a chance to expand sda 3?

Comment: Yes, just use the "Move/resize" dialog. It won't let you move or shrink a mounted partition, but it should let you grow it (to the full size of the "sda" disk, if you want).

Comment: Thank you very much. I did as you said. Problem solved.

Comment: @LutfuKacaran, if an answer answers you question, please be so kind to accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a place to backup the contents of the new partition then you can blow away the new partition, and resize the original to fill the disk in gparted, then copy the other partitions contents back to the first partition.

Also a little caveat regarding raid 0.

Striped raid devices don't have any redundancy. When one of the drives go you could be facing very large data loss.

From my understanding contents of files and directories will be written across the raid nodes.